# How to embed a SVG symbol with pyQGIS

Tags: svg, pyqgis

In a python QGIS plugin, how can I embed a SVG symbol, as if I used the 'Embed file' function in a svg marker symbology in QGIS (at the end we don't need the svg file anymore, the svg description should be embedded into the symbology definition)?